# Selenium Web Scraping C# - Return Views

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I am going to this web page

https://www.bidrl.com/auction/high-end-auction-3920-w-capitol-ave-ste-150-west-sac-monday-sept-25-at-630pm-134960/item/camplux-portable-tankless-water-heater-158-gpm-17730099/

Trying to return the value in the field “Item Has Been Viewed Field”
I can get the Title ok but have tried lots of combinations on the Viewed field but cant get anything returned
All I actually want returned is the number if I had a choice

Trying to return this value:
[image]

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace WebScraperDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bidrl.com/auction/high-end-auction-3920-w-capitol-ave-ste-150-west-sac-monday-sept-25-at-630pm-134960/item/camplux-portable-tankless-water-heater-158-gpm-17730099/");

            //this line works - Title
            string text1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@ng-bind-html='item.title']")).Text;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text1);

            //dont work - Views
            string text2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='viewed-item']")).Text;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text2);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible for me to download a copy of the project somehow.
I tried to recreate what you have done but cant quite get it to work.
This is new for me – I have only done database programming until now.
Would love to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is indeed a possible way to webscrape.
I've looked at the network traffic for this website and turns out there is an  api endpoint where the webpage requests all the item-data, so also the number of times viewed.
In this case a simple http request will solve this without the need for selenium, drivers, webbrowser, ....

A possible reason for why you are not able to find this data using selenium is because of the fact the itemdata is loaded in separately. Adding a delay between loading the webpage and finding the data will probably fix your current approach.

[Post request url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HZ1A.png)

analyzing your url:

https://www.bidrl.com/auction/high-end-auction-3920-w-capitol-ave-ste-150-west-sac-monday-sept-25-at-630pm-134960/item/camplux-portable-tankless-water-heater-158-gpm-17730099/

In this url I found the following: item_id = 17730099, auction_id = 134960 which is used as the payload for the http POST request in order to retrieve the item data.
In the JSON response to this request you can see it contains the "viewed" key with the value you want.

[JSON response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRHYH.png)

Turns out the entire bid history is in this data and a bunch of other useful information so you could retrieve all useful information with 1 call.

Make sure you use a CookieContainer to create a session since you will need a valid session id in your POST request.

So you will probably end up doing the following:
GET request to the url you've provided in order to set the correct session id,
POST request to the api endpoint in order to get the itemdata

```
    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    // Make a GET request to get the cookies.
    HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("your_url_here");
    getRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

    HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();

    // Save the cookies to the cookieContainer.
    cookieContainer.Add(getResponse.Cookies);

    // Make a POST request to login.
    HttpWebRequest postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.bidrl.com/api/ItemData");
    postRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    postRequest.Method = "POST";

    // Set the request content.
    string postData = "item_id=17730099&auction_id=134960";
    postRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(postRequest);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The responseBody variable will now contain all the itemData.

This is a different approach then you''ve intended but it's more lightweight and you can easily integrate it in any operating system, run it in the background, ....

Since the result is what you wanted i hope this answered your question